# Get title string from url within iframe using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I wonder if it is possible to get the page title of an url within IFRAME. I tried to use jQuery $('#iframe').attr('title') but that doesn't work. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert($('#iframe').contents().find("title").text());
});
```

That will return the page title that is located in the `<title>` tag of the iframe document that has the id "iframe".

Answer (score 1):

I misread your question.

```
$('title', frames[frameName].document).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is a way to get the URL of the iframe *after* the user has clicked on a link within that iframe, this is not possible in any modern browser that blocks cross-domain attempts.

Even though the iframe is part of the DOM and you can easily find the new iframe URL using apps like Firebug, Firefox will throw a XSS error on any attempts by js to directly pull that info.

But for the record, as it's already been said, the location within the DOM of the actual URL of the iframe content is (with a little help from jquery) : `$("#id_of_iframe).contentDocument.location.href`

I'm not totally sure if the above points straight to it with the above syntax, but that's the gist of it. The part that is a no-no is trying to go inside that `contentDocument` part.